# How to call the elements in jsf page when join is used

Tags: eclipse, jsf, primefaces

I have three tables `student` , `result` , `student_result`

In `Student` entities are `Id` ,`name`
In `result` entities are `studentId`, `marks`
In `student_result` entities is `StudentId`

In `jsf` page i have to display name by using `studentid` in intermediary table.
 and i dont know how to pass the value in jsf page . Please help me for that

Comment: Could you provide the entities' main codes ?

Answer (score 0):

You can access all the data of student using "Student Id". Just you need to define relationship between the tables and then recapture the database again. Then you can access all other field/properties of students.